# Am I expected to receive Facebook SMS even after deleting my account long ago?

Tags: facebook, profile, facebook-notifications, facebook-account

I deleted my account long back, but I am still getting(but not very frequently but twice a day) these SMS alerts. Is this behavior expected? What can I do to stop receiving these SMSs.

Answer (score 1):

Type "off" and send it to 32665 as a normal text massage. [source](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=258443797636955&answer_id=327979324016735&rdrhc).

Comment: Apparently I can't send this message from my number as it is post paid.  Is there any other way to do same thing.